# Menu div filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, menu

First of all, I am beginner with JS. I need somebody to give me info how understand one thing.

I have menu which has got 3 categories and divs. Every div has got one or two categories. What I need is make something like filter - if you select RED on menu, show all divs with class .RED; if you select RED and BLUE, show all divs with both classes .RED and .BLUE.

I know that this is connected with JSON, but how to start and understand it? Please show me some examples on Codepen to better understand this topic.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us your code for the menu so that we can work from there?

Comment: Asking for us to recommend a resource is not allowed on SO. If you show your work, we can help fix it, otherwise your question will be deleted.

Comment: It has nothing to do with json unless you are encoding data to send to a server.

Comment: @Rob sorry for no code guys, I have written it on smartphone. Here is code. I know that it is wrong but I am beginner... I did not use JSON, but pretty simple jQuery stuff. Please check it:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWpmKQ

Comment: @Damon Anyone can help me?

Comment: Is it still broken? Seems to be working.

Comment: Code on third party sites is not allowed. That code can be changed or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future. You are required to post a minimal example that shows the problem here.

Comment: @Damon yes, but I have to make it by JSON